# Data annotation in Servicestack References vs ForeignKey

Tags: servicestack, data-annotations, ormlite-servicestack

Well, in ServiceStack
where can I read up on the merits and differences of
[References(typeof(ABC))]    and
[ForeignKey(typeof(XYZ) ]

What are they used for ?  (I know, rather naively put but I have a hard time finding the basic description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for both are referenced throughout [ServiceStack.OrmLite project page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite).

#### Use either for simple Foreign Keys

Essentially they're both equivalent to define simple Foreign Keys which you can use either for:

```
[References(typeof(ForeignKeyTable1))]
public int SimpleForeignKey { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable1))]
public int SimpleForeignKey { get; set; }
```

The `[References]` attribute is also used by other data persistence libraries like [PocoDynamo for DynamoDb](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) where it would be preferred when wanting to re-use your existing data models else where, it's also useful as a benign "marker" attribute on different models when you want to include a navigable reference to an associated type for the property.

#### Fine-grained Foreign Key options

The `[ForeignKey]` is specific to OrmLite and includes additional fine-grained options for defining foreign key relationships specific to RDBMS's like different cascading options, e.g:

```
public class TableWithAllCascadeOptions
{
    [AutoIncrement] public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable1))]
    public int SimpleForeignKey { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable2), OnDelete = "CASCADE", OnUpdate = "CASCADE")]
    public int? CascadeOnUpdateOrDelete { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable3), OnDelete = "NO ACTION")]
    public int? NoActionOnCascade { get; set; }

    [Default(typeof(int), "17")]
    [ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable4), OnDelete = "SET DEFAULT")]
    public int SetToDefaultValueOnDelete { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(ForeignKeyTable5), OnDelete = "SET NULL")]
    public int? SetToNullOnDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mythz.
Tried to find some description of OnDelete,  OnUpdate.   
What can they be set to ?   
Any hints ?

Comment: @EnTermosJava It's up to whatever your RDBMS supports. Most support `CASCADE`, others are more RDBMS-specific.